# Python: Replace a specific word in value of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary

`a = {'url' : 'https://www.abcd.com'}`

How to use replace and removed `'https://www.'` and just be `'abcd.com'`?

I tried

`a = [w.replace('https://www.', '') for w in a]`

But it only return the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dictionary has more entries:

```
a_new = {k:v.replace('https://www.', '') for k,v in a.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You access the values of the dictionary using: `a['url']`
and then you update the string value of url using the replace function:

```py
a['url'] = a['url'].replace('https://www.', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to iterate on, just retrieve the key, modify it, and save it

```
a = {'url': 'https://www.abcd.com'}
a['url'] = a['url'].replace('https://www.', '')
print(a)  # {'url': 'abcd.com'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for dict comprehension is slightly different:

`a = {key: value.replace('https://www.', '') for key, value in a.items()}`

As per documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

And https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques for `dict.items()`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your result to be a dictionary:

```
a = {k: v.replace('https://www.', '') for k, v in a.items()}
```

if you want your result to be an array:

```
a = [v.replace('https://www.', '') for v in a.values()]
```

More on dictionary comprehension here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/